# click button type='button element with selenium webdriver in class using python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmGGU.png)

I am trying to click on this for whole day with python selenium with no luck, tried several selectors, xpath..nothing seems to be work for me. This is the element I try to click on:
i need to click on the button on sharepoint.com

CODE

```
log_but2 = "//button[@class='o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365button ms-bgc-tdr-h o365cs-topnavText' and role='menuitem']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(log_but2).click()
```

It failed

Problem : I need to open the onedrive from sharepoint.com(image attached)

HTML CODE :

```
<button type="button" class="o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365button ms-bgc-tdr-h o365cs-topnavText" role="menuitem" title="Open the app launcher to access Office 365 apps" id="O365_MainLink_NavMenu_Responsive" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" aria-label="App launcher">
<span class="owaimg ms-Icon ms-Icon--Waffle ms-icon-font-size-24 o365cs-topnavText" aria-hidden="true">
</span><div class="o365cs-flexPane-unseenitems"> 
<span class="o365cs-flexPane-unseenCount ms-bgc-tdr ms-fcl-w" style="display: none;">
</span> <span class="o365cs-flexPane-unseenCount owaimg ms-Icon--starburst ms-icon-font-size-12 ms-bgc-tdr ms-fcl-w" style="display: none;"> 
</span> </div></button>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you have tried. You can [edit] it into your question. If possible, include a [mcve]. This helps us understand your question better, and improves your chance of getting a useful answer. I can only see the imports.

Comment: 1- Post html as text, not image 2- share the code that failed 3- explain what caused the failure (if you have an exception post the stack trace as well).

Answer (score 0):

As a blind stab in the dark, try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'ms-Icon')][contains(text(), 'OneDrive')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the *button* with text as **App launcher** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='o365cs-nav-item o365cs-nav-button o365button ms-bgc-tdr-h o365cs-topnavText' and @id='O365_MainLink_NavMenu_Responsive']"))).click()
```

Comment: i need to click on the href so:-

Comment: @sanjanakapoor I didn't get your question. The _HTML_ doesn't contain any `href` as such.